# MySQL MYISAM: Запись большого количества данных, защита от сбоя

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, что можно сделать для уменьшения негативных последствий от сбоя в процессе записи в БД MySQL большого массива данных (т.е. при нажатии одной кнопки Submit должна осуществиться запись поочередно в 6 связанных таблиц (число записей, кот. будут вставлены, либо обновлены в каждой из таблиц - от 1 до 30 ), при этом отсутствует механизм транзакций). Необходимо, чтобы в случае ошибки пользователь обязательно получил сообщение о том, что такая-то часть данных не записалась.
Пока я думаю делать на php проверки после каждого шага сохранения. Есть ли  уже в БД записи предыдущего шага сохранения. Но не может ли быть каких-то ситуаций, что этого будет недостаточно? 
Заказчик еще хочет, чтобы в случае ошибки на любом этапе записи произошел полный откат. Получается, это тоже только самой писать скрипт удаления из БД уже успевшего записаться до сбоя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По хорошему с такими требованиями заказчика - нужно рекомендовать переходить на движек таблиц InnoDB и использовать полноценные транзакции (собственно, они для этого и нужны).

Если это невозможно - то да - рисовать велосипед самому. На каждом шаге вставки писать в массив (стек) значения вида - таблица-новыйИД (ну или готовый запрос сразу, если вам так больше нравится) и в случае ошибки выполнять удаления по этому массиву.

Строго говоря, MyISAM весьма примитивный тип таблиц, и ошибка вставки там может быть либо при синтаксических ошибках в запросе, либо при впихивании поля null туда, где его быть не должно. Поэтому - проверяйте это тщательно на клиенте и случаи отката "транзакции" будут минимальны.